# Weird "classname" has not been declared

Tags: c++, c++11

container.hpp

```
#ifndef CONTAINER_HPP
#define CONTAINER_HPP

#include <functional>


namespace lasd {

/* ************************************************************************** */

class Container {

private:

  // ...

protected:

  unsigned long size = 0;

public:

  // Destructor
  virtual ~Container() = default;

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Copy assignment
  Container& operator=(const Container&) = delete; // Not usable.

  // Move assignment
  Container& operator=(Container&) = delete; // Not usable.

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Comparison operators
  bool operator==(const Container&) const noexcept = delete; // Not usable.
  bool operator!=(const Container&) const noexcept = delete; // Not usable.

  /* ************************************************************************ */

  // Specific member functions

  virtual inline bool Empty() const noexcept;

  virtual inline unsigned long Size() const noexcept;

  virtual void Clear() = 0;

};

#include "container.cpp"

}

#endif
```

container.cpp

```
// Specific member functions (Container)


inline unsigned long Container::Size() const noexcept{
  return size;
}

inline bool Container::Empty() const noexcept{
  return size == 0;
}
```

Give this in output. The funniest part is that all this code is provided by my professor, and I only have coded the .cpp file. I've already tried to add #include "container.hpp" to my .cpp file.

```
||=== Build: Debug in Exercise1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||=== Build: Debug in Exercise1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|4|error: 'Container' has not been declared|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|4|error: non-member function 'long unsigned int Size()' cannot have cv-qualifier|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp||In function 'long unsigned int Size()':|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|5|error: 'size' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|8|error: 'Container' has not been declared|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|8|error: non-member function 'bool Empty()' cannot have cv-qualifier|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp||In function 'bool Empty()':|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|9|error: 'size' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Giulia\Desktop\Università\Laboratorio ASD\exercise1\container\container.cpp|38|error: expected initializer before '<' token|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

During professor video lectures, he has compiled the code and it worked so well. I really cannot understand why, by using Code::Blocks, it gives me this error (I've tried on the gpp-compiler on Atom editor too, with the exactly same result).

Thanks.

Comment: Your professor gave you some code that had `#include "container.cpp"`? Is he a beginner at C++?

Comment: That `#include "container.cpp"` in header file and within namespace scope makes me shiver...

Comment: If you are allowed, remove the line in your header that says `#include "container.cpp"` and much confusion will be avoided. If you can't then the second best option would be to change courses.

Comment: and place `namespace lasd { ... }` around the member functions in `container.cpp`.

Comment: Also this move assignment operator: `Container& operator=(Container&) = delete;` is wrong. It should be `Container& operator=(Container&&) = delete;`

Comment: I'm going to be generous and say that eventually this class is going to become a template class, and the professor is using the well known trick to make it seem that you can seperate interface and implementation in a template. Still rubbish though, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could edit the header file. However, I still suppose that the professor wrote these volountary mistakes to let us correct them (I hope is that!).

Comment: Is that something your professor has done in the past? It'd be cruel to not give you a heads up if the task is to fix the errors.  You said "_he has compiled the code and it worked so well_" - Is it possible to see if this is the same code as in the video?

Comment: I solved by removing that wrong #include "container.cpp" in the h file, adding #include "container.hpp" and namespacing lasd in the .cpp. Thank you guys!

Comment: Don't forget to fix the erroneous move assignment operator :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm in doubt right now, maybe the code that he compiled wasn't the wrong one... And no, he never did it in the past nor give any infos about correcting errors. I think it's a mistake of himself.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sure, I'll do that!

Comment: For your sake, I really hope it wasn't a _mistake_. It's better to have a cruel professor than a totally incompetent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, in your project you are compiling `container.cpp` separately, as any reasonable project would do. However, your professor did something that would never pass any code review - he included a cpp file in a header file.

You need to change your project to not compile `container.cpp` separately (or better yet, get rid of that include and fix `container.cpp` to make it possible to compile it).

Comment: Actually the change that's needed here is change of professors.

Comment: I've removed that wrong #include, added namespace lasd{ ..} around the block, but nothing has changed, the compiler give the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Note the `namespace lasd` in your header file. You should either explicitly namespace every function in your cpp file (`lasd::Container::Size`) or also wrap it in a `namespace lasd { ... }` block.

Comment: But notice the header file. it does `#include "container.cpp"` within the lasd namespace! And this header was given to the student by the professor!

Comment: @john It's probably both including it _and_ compiling it on its own. Scary :-)

Comment: I did not see that #include .. oh dear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes my thought too, hard to blame the student for doing the proper thing though.

Comment: I've already tried to add namespace lasd{ ...} or using namespace lasd; however it doesn't work.

Comment: The compiler says that "lasd" namespace has not been declared.

Comment: @RalphTheCreator Your CPP file is supposed to include the header file. Not the other way round!

Comment: @RalphTheCreator You have to work out the confusion about what is including what. If you have the header include the cpp file (as your professor gave you) then you should not have the cpp file include the header file and you should not separately compile the cpp file. But if you do things the normal way, then you cpp file should include your header file, and you should separately compile the cpp file. You need to decide which route you are going to take. The second route is the sensible one, but I realise that your professor might insist on the first option.

Comment: @john However I'll give him the proofs that my (our) reason is working better than his one.